# How can I download one of several files, depending on a selected radio button?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have some HTML that includes two radio buttons. Depending on which radio button has been selected, I want to download one of two files. How can I do that?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function downloadAddin(){
            document.getElementById("bit32");
            if (document.getElementById("bit32").checked) {
                document.location.href="ECSSetup32.exe";
            } else {
                document.location.href="ECSSetup64.exe";
            }
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <form>
        <p><input type="radio" id="bit32" name="arch" checked>Windows 32-bit
        <br><input type="radio" id="bit64" name="arch">Windows 64-bit
        <p>
        <button type="submit" onclick="downloadAddin()"id="download_button"   
         style="background-color: #0078FF; padding: 1%; color: #ffffff; border:1px    
         solid; border-radius:10px; font-size:75%">Accept and Download</button>
    </form>
```

I want users to be able to choose a radio button, press the "Agree and Download" button and then get one of the two .exe files they requested. Any ideas?

Comment: FYI you will get a negative reception to your question if you don't show what you have tried and ask about a specific problem you are having.

Comment: What @Nick just said. Then again, looking for something like this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kz2hw/2/) ?

Comment: OK, I've updated the question; sorry if it was unclear.

Comment: I just noticed that some donkeys trashed my post with -4 votes. If I don't see any replies soon, I'll repost it.

Comment: @akinuri Thanks, that's exactly what I need! How can I give you credit for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple JS code will do the job.

```
<input type="radio" name="download" id="x86"/>winrar x86 <br />
<input type="radio" name="download" id="x64"/>winrar x64 <br />
<input type="button" id="download" value="download"/>
```

```
var radio_x86 = document.getElementById('x86');
var radio_x64 = document.getElementById('x64');

var button = document.getElementById('download');

button.onclick = downloadFile;

function downloadFile() {
    if(radio_x86.checked) {
        window.open("http://www.rarlab.com/rar/wrar500.exe");
    }else if(radio_x64.checked) {
        window.open("http://www.rarlab.com/rar/winrar-x64-500.exe");
    } else {
        alert("Please check one of the options first.");
    }
}
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kz2hw/2/)

**EDIT:** [Fiddle: your own code](http://jsfiddle.net/XRgyn/2/) 
You don't need to wrap your input elements with `<form>` tag unless you're using post/get.

Comment: Thanks again, akinuri. The two lines in downloadFil() were what I was looking for.